# Can you explain how are filters populated in the search results page of Magento?

Tags: magento

Specifically,

My filters that should be showing up on the search page are not doing so, and I am wondering if anyone was aware of the location in code that they are attached to the Layer object.

eg: on `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/View.php` they are loaded up with the call to `$this->getLayer()->getFilterableAttributes()` in the `_getFilterableAttributes()` function. But beyond that I am confused as to where they come from.

Comment: so do a grep ' getFilterableAttributes' app/code -rsn to get the file where this method is defined

Comment: Yup, I did that, it doesn't help much. As I said I am confused beyond that point. I am pretty much looking for a high level quick tutorial saying where the variables are set.

Comment: Look at the properties of the attribute in question in the backend.  Under "Frontend Properties" you have to enable "Use In Layered Navigation"....I think...or maybe it's "Use in Product Listing"...try both.  But I'm pretty sure it's one of those ;)

Comment: Which version of Magento do you use, in newer Magento version you have to enable 'Use In Search Results Layered Navigation'. After enabling this, or in earlier Magento versions enable the usage in layered navigation, you have to preform a full reindex and cache flush.